# Android Composable + LiveData - not recomposing

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LiveData<List<*>>` that is passed to a composable.
I use `.observeAsState` in the composable to convert that `LiveData` to a `State`.

When I update a lap, by setting it as invalid for example, the `LiveData` is correctly updated (confirmed by observers being triggered in other part of the app) but the **Composable is not recomposed**.

Not sure if it's relevant but the Composable is in a `ComposeView` inside a XML layout (rest of layout uses a chart library that doesn't support Compose).

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the cause of the issue.

Below is an extract of the code:

```
class AnalysisFragment(private val session: Session): Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mActivity: MainActivity
    private lateinit var sessionViewModel: SessionsViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    mActivity = activity as MainActivity
    sessionViewModel = ViewModelProvider(mActivity)[SessionsViewModel::class.java]

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_analysis, container, false).apply {
            findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeView).setContent {
                val listLaps = sessionViewModel.getLapsOfSession(session.getId())
                AppCompatTheme {
                    AnalysisOverviewCompose(
                        laps = listLaps,
                        onLapLongPress = sessionViewModel::onLapLongPress)
                }
            }
        }
}


@Composable
fun AnalysisOverviewCompose(laps: LiveData<List<Lap>>,
                            onLapLongPress: (Lap) -> Unit) {

    val listLaps by laps.observeAsState(initial = emptyList())
    if (listLaps.isNotEmpty()) {
        LapsTable(listLaps, onLapLongPress) // This is a LazyColumn
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't use `viewModels`/`viewModel` as showed in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)? Yet your code should work fine, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I think I'm facing the same issue with an IF statement in a Composable inside an XML layout. It seems after the IF condition is false, it just stops recomposing. So even if the IF condition changes back to true (in my case set by a preference), it won't show the Composable within the IF statement.

Comment: Try constructing a new instance of the collection.  If you update a collection and then try to re-emit it, the LiveData will recognize that it is the same object (ignoring that it has been changed) and not emit the new value.